# Different version info for different builds?

Tags: visual-studio, resource-files

I have a C++ project in Visual Studio.  This project results in several different builds, and I would like the different builds to report different File descriptions and product names.  Version numbers, menus, dialogs, etc are all the same, so I don't want to use a different resource file.

Is there a way to override some individual items of the resource information, or split it off into another file?  There doesn't seem to be any way to split the version block in the resource editor - it's all or nothing.

Alternatively, should I script a resource editor into the Post-Build to rewrite one or two items of the version info for certain builds?  I can find a few GUI resource editors on the net, but none that are scriptable into my build events.

Answer (score 0):

I found a nice little open-source command-line utility, called verpatch.  It is able to update the resource information on the compiled exe, and I have just scripted it into the post-build step for my product.  It works nicely.